# Python 3 tkinker - How do i get this code output into the gui?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How do I get this code into my gui? I tried adding it into a button but failed!

I want all of `def say_hi(self)` inside the gui rather then printing it to the shell, also the printout works best in the console rather then python shell!

```
import sys
import time
from random import randint
import tkinter as tk
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()
        # self.roll is the button 

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.roll = tk.Button(self)
        self.roll["text"] = "rolldice"
        self.roll["command"] = self.say_hi
        self.roll.pack(side="left")
        #self.quit is the kill button
        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                              command=root.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="right")
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text='ROLL THE DICE !')
        self.label.pack()
        # this is my loading result.

    def say_hi(self):

        d = 0
        for x in range(0,7):
            for x in range (0,5):  
                b = "Loading" + "." * x
                a = "                           "
                print (b, end="\r")
                time.sleep(0.1)
                print (a, end="\r")
                time.sleep(0)

        print("finished rolling!")
        time.sleep(2)
        for x in range(0,7):
            for x in range (0,5):  
                b = "printing" + "." * x
                a = "                           "
                print (b, end="\r")
                time.sleep(0.1)
                print (a, end="\r")
                time.sleep(0)
        print ("printed")
        print ("here it is thankyou for using us!")
        print ("                                          ")
        value = randint(1, 6)
        self.label['text'] = value
        self.label.pack()


root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried using a label and update text in it ?

Comment: And your code has messed up indentation levels.

Comment: no because I'm in the process of learning how to use tk could you please show me?

Comment: it came out of a few "if" statements sorry!

Comment: Your output consists of multiple Loadings and multiple prints and then finally prints the value is that how you want it to be ?

Comment: yes it is and if you run it in console rather then shell it replaces the line giving a sort of animation look

Comment: Check out the answer I've posted.

Comment: _"... but failed"_ is too vague. Why did it fail? What is the code doing that's different from what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Lable` and `StringVar`.

The Label widget is a standard Tkinter widget used to display a text or image on the screen. The label can only display text in a single font, but the text may span more than one line. In addition, one of the characters can be underlined, for example, to mark a keyboard shortcut.

Here is a good explanation on how to use it [check it out!](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm).

**Edit**

If you want the user to be able to display data that the user can manipulate in place, it’s probably easier to use the [Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) widget.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Instead of printing 

`self.label['text'] = b
self.label.pack()
root.update()`

It updates the values which are being printed right inside the widget.

```
import sys
import time
from random import randint
import tkinter as tk
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()
        # self.roll is the button 

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.roll = tk.Button(self)
        self.roll["text"] = "rolldice"
        self.roll["command"] = self.say_hi
        self.roll.pack(side="left")
        #self.quit is the kill button
        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                              command=root.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="right")
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text='ROLL THE DICE !', padx=20)
        self.label.pack()
        # this is my loading result.

    def say_hi(self):

        d = 0
        for x in range(0,7):
            for x in range (0,5):  
                b = "Loading" + "." * x
                a = "                           "
                #self.label.pack_forget()
                self.label['text'] = b
                self.label.pack()
                #root.update_idletasks()
                root.update()
                print (b, end="\r")
                time.sleep(0.2)
                print (a, end="\r")
                time.sleep(0)

        print("finished rolling!")


        for x in range(0,7):
            for x in range (0,5):
                b = "Printing" + "." * x
                a = "                           "
                #self.label.pack_forget()
                self.label['text'] = b
                self.label.pack()
                #root.update_idletasks()
                root.update()
                print (b, end="\r")
                time.sleep(0.2)
                print (a, end="\r")
                time.sleep(0)
        print ("printed")
        print ("here it is thankyou for using us!")
        print ("                                          ")
        value = randint(1, 6)
        self.label['text'] = value
        self.label.pack()

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: looks like it ;(

Comment: I'm not in school and it's not my homework lol I just wanted to learn python but thank you anyway i will look at the website too!